# How to save multiple file in phpexcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

For example I have 5000 data. 
I'm trying to split these data 1000 for each file in excel.

Saw this example :

Create two workbooks

```
($objPHPExcelFile1=new PHPExcel(); $objPHPExcelFile2=new PHPExcel();
```

so I did this

```
    $jco=1; $jcos=1;
    $trig=0; $rowNya = 2;
    $no = 0;


if ($VinDB->num_rows($result) != 0)
{

    while($line = $VinDB->fetch_array($result)){

        if($trig ==0 )
        {   
            $objPHPExcel[$jcos] = new PHPExcel();
            $objPHPExcel[$jcos]->getProperties()->setCreator("Test")
            ->setLastModifiedBy("Test")
            ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
            ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
            ->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
            ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
            ->setCategory("result file");

            $trig=1;

        }

        $no = $no +1;
        if($jco <= 1000){
        $objPHPExcel[$jcos]->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue("A$rowNya", $no)
            ->setCellValue("B$rowNya", @$line["NoTransaksi"])
            ->setCellValue("C$rowNya", @$line["Pesan"])
            ->setCellValue("D$rowNya", @$line["Jam"])
            ->setCellValue("E$rowNya", @$line["Alias"])
            ->setCellValue("F$rowNya", @$line["Nomor_hp"])
            ->setCellValue("G$rowNya", @$line["GroupKU"])
            ->setCellValue("H$rowNya", @$line["Report"])
            ->setCellValue("I$rowNya", @$line["Status"])
            ->setCellValue("J$rowNya", @$line["Token"]);
            $rowNya = $rowNya + 1;
        $jco++; 
        }

        else{
        $jco=1;
        $trig=0;

            $objPHPExcel[$jcos]->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');
            $objPHPExcel[$jcos]->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


            header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Report_part'.$jcos.'.xls"');
            header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

            $objWriter[$jcos] = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel[$jcos], 'Excel5');
            $objWriter[$jcos]->save('php://output');

        $jcos++;

        }
    }
}
```

It worked for the first 1000 data there's a save button, but for the part 2 its not working.  Can anyone help me. Here the screenshot:

[image]

**Latest**:
Ok so ..i cant upload multiple files to browser, so i just do multiple sheet and save it on my local disk, but how do i download it from my localhost/server

[image]

here's my code

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('/xampp/htdocs/sms/Report_'.$jcos.'.xls');
$file = 'sms/Report_'.$jcos.'.xls';
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
readfile($file);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't send multiple files to the browser. Save your workbooks to disk, pack them into one file (e.g. zip) and send this single file to the browser.

**Edit**

After your while loop you can add:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('/xampp/htdocs/sms/Reports.zip', ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
$zip->addGlob('/xampp/htdocs/sms/Report_*.xls');
$zip->close();
```

Please have a look at the [docs](http://php.net/manual/class.ziparchive.php) for more options.

at last:

```
$file = '/xampp/htdocs/sms/Reports.zip';
header('Content-type: application/zip'); // Please check this, i just guessed
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
readfile($file);
```

Comment: how do i download the file from my locahost server?